# express.js handle any error in global level

Tags: node.js, express

express.js code handle any global error

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
        if (!err) {
        return next();
        }
    
        res.status(500);
        res.send("500: Internal server error");
    });
```

I have above code to handle global error and send silent response without crashing entire app
but still app is  crashing . Is it correct way to handle any error ?

```
    app listening on port: 5600
    /Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/cnox/cnoxbackend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4678
      const castError = new CastError();
                        ^
    
    CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "62626524a4722bf9b398d8f5ddd" (type string) at path "_id" for model "customer"
        at model.Query.exec (/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/cnox/cnoxbackend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4678:21)
        at model.Query.Query.then (/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/cnox/cnoxbackend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4777:15)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
      messageFormat: undefined,
```

Comment: are you using express routers?

Comment: like this.
const express = require("express");
const customerRoutes = express.Router();

Comment: I have had lots of problems with express routers and error handling. It seems like you have to declare error handling for each router like `customRoutes.use((err, req, res, next) => `... Otherwise it will not work